# How to fix "[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error: ORDER BY is not allowed in subqueries." in tableau query

Tags: tableau-api

i'm create a query that to pull a data from teradata that will use in tableau, which part of my query that i need to fix it?

this query i have tried in Teradata sql asisstant, its worked, but when i move to tableau its always end up with error ORDER BY is not allowed in subquerie

below the teradata sql query :

```
    Select  
    ChannelType,Group,
    LevelType,
    EXTRACT(YEAR From CDate) as KYear, 
    EXTRACT(MOnth From CDate) as KMonth, 

    Case 
    when Position('Live' IN modeType) >0 then 'L'
    else 'S'
    end as LS,

    Sum(watch) as Watches,
    Sum(amount) as amounts
    zeroifnull(amounts)/zeroifnull(Watches,)as result,

    CASE 
    WHEN result >0 then 'WIN'
    ELSE 'LOSE'
    END AS WL Class

    From Mart_wodo.data where
    CDate between date'2018-01-01' and date'2018-12-31'  and
    Group in('L1','L2','L3','L4','L5') and
    LevelType NOT IN('0') and 
    Channeltype in('TV','TY,'IG')

    Group By Channeltype , Group, LevelType, KYear, KMonth,LS

    Order BY  KYear, KMonth,Channeltype, Group,LS asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is Tableau is wrapping your query in an outer `SELECT`, which is why you're getting the `ORDER BY not allowed` error message, but it works as-is in SQL Assistant.

If that's the case, you'd need to remove the `ORDER BY` clause and see if you can specify the final ordering via Tableau. Or possibly wrap your SQL in a view and access the view via Tableau: [link](https://community.tableau.com/thread/184557)

As a potential hack (it probably won't work), you can try re-ordering the `GROUP BY` columns or adding a dummy window function with an `ORDER BY` clause and see if that has any effect:

```sql
Select  
  ChannelType,Group,
  ...
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY KYear, KMonth, Channeltype, Group, LS ASC) AS RowNum

From Mart_wodo.data where
CDate between date'2018-01-01' and date'2018-12-31'  and
Group in('L1','L2','L3','L4','L5') and
LevelType NOT IN('0') and 
Channeltype in('TV','TY,'IG')

Group By KYear, KMonth, Channeltype, Group, LS, LevelType
```

Comment: Awesome!!  You're welcome.  Did you use a view or the `ORDER BY` hack?  If you used the hack, I would be careful with that since the behavior might change across TD releases and you may not be able to rely on it 100%.

Comment: I'm using 'ORDER BY' in a dummy's windows function as you suggested before. and yah seems like related with TD releases. need to be careful with it, since TDSA no longer can be used as a standard test platform for queries that we want to use it in tableau